# How can an array size be extended to range of long in java and if not possible what other data structure can be used for the same

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, range, long-integer

How can an array size be extended to range of `long` in Java? and, if not possible, wwhat other data structure can be used for the same?

Comment: all the java containers use `int` as index.

Comment: Are you asking out of intellectual curiosity or do you actually have an application where you feel that a couple billion elements in an array is just not enough?

Comment: Hint: simply repeating the question title does not make up a good answer. Instead you might better describe the problem you intend to solve. What are you doing that requires arrays with "long" indexes?

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are built-in constructs. You cannot influence their indexing scheme in any way, so you would have to use `int` index.

Similarly, all Java collections are limited to 2<sup>31</sup> entries, because their `size()` method returns an `int`, and direct access methods, where available, also take an `int`.

If you need a data structure that stores more than 2<sup>31</sup> items, make a 2D array of "chunks", each representing a portion of a "big" array. In essence, you would build your own class that translates `long` addressing to a pair of `int`s for emulating a linear indexing space.

Comment: I think it is not exactly 2 power 31... There are various questions around that discuss the exact number of entries Java arrays can hold. But you are correct, if long is required, you need to build that yourself.

Comment: To extend the answer: While there are numerous different implementations of `Collection` data-structures, they all are limited in their size as they use an `int` for that. However you can easily extend some of those implementations to support `long`. For example `arrays` or `ArrayList` can be extended by using multiple arrays once one is full (like `BigInteger` does to extend the size of `int`). Also `LinkedList` can very easily be extended without any problem. The same holds for some `Set`, `Map` and `Queue` approaches.

Answer (score 0):

java arrays are limited to 2<sup>31</sup> less a few elements that vary depending on the specific VM implementation.

One way to solve this is to use arrays of arrays, with a maximum single array length of 2<sup>31</sup> - 9 elements, so making sure we don't get past the VM limit

```
long wishedArraySize = 3_000_000_000L;
long maxVMArraySize = 2_147_483_639;  // Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8
byte[][] myHugeArray = new byte[(int)((wishedArraySize - 1L) / maxVMArraySize + 1L)][];
for (int i = 0; i < myHugeArray.length; ++i) {
    myHugeArray[i] = new byte[(int)(i < myHugeArray.length - 1 ? maxVMArraySize : (wishedArraySize - i * maxVMArraySize))];
}
long index = 2_345_678_901L;  // random number > 2 Gig
System.out.println(myHugeArray[(int)(index / maxVMArraySize)][(int)(index % maxVMArraySize)]);
```

We can optimize and avoid those division and modulo operations if we stick to an array size multiple of a power of 2. The biggest power of 2 size is 1 Gig elements

```
long wishedArraySize = 3_000_000_000L;
long maxPowerOf2ArraySize = 1L << 30; // 1 Gig == 1_073_741_824 == 2^30
byte[][] myHugeArray = new byte[(int)(((wishedArraySize - 1L) >> 30) + 1L)][];
for (int i = 0; i < myHugeArray.length; ++i) {
    myHugeArray[i] = new byte[(int)(i < myHugeArray.length - 1 ? maxPowerOf2ArraySize : (wishedArraySize - i * maxPowerOf2ArraySize))];
}
long lowerThan1GigMask = 0x0_3f_ff_ff_ffL;  // == 1_073_741_823 == 2^30 - 1
long index = 2_345_678_901L;  // random number > 2 Gig
System.out.println(myHugeArray[(int)(index >> 30)][(int)(index & lowerThan1GigMask)]);
```

We could put it all nicely inside a class, but the main difference is accessing the array, from

`myLimitedArray[index]`

to

`myHugeArray[(int)(index >> 30)][(int)(index & lowerThan1GigMask)]`